# Time measurement in the Linux kernel

Tags: linux, kernel, time

I want to measure time intervals in my kernel. I know nanoseconds are not really precise but I need more precision than milliseconds.

There are many many functions to get a time. Jiffies, time of day, time without sleeping, time with sleeping... There is ktime_get, clock_gettime, sys_clock_gettime and others.
I looked into the functions and feel like some enormous machinery is started in them. I don't need conversion to time of day and I also want to avoid converting values back and forth from and to several time-keeping structs.

For a start without respecting performance I thought I am fine with

```
struct compat_timespec cts;
compat_sys_clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &cts);
```

It worked until I wanted to use it in a file open function of a virtual file. Now `compat_sys_clock_gettime` returns an error code. What can cause an error reading a time?

So my question is embarrassingly basic.

How can I performantly just get the nanoseconds since booting the PC...

- without subtracting sleep times or any other special conditions,
- without a possibility of failure?

My simple imagination is there should be a function that reads a ticker value from somewhere and multiplies / divides this value to get ns out of it. I'd also appreciate to learn why it's not so easy.

Comment: You could find a hardware source (such as the `powerpc` _time base register_ - see [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/__ppc_get_timebase.3.html)) - but sounds to me like using _jiffies_ would be good enough - you can get a `timespec` from _jiffies_ using `jiffies_to_timespec()`. Have a read of [this](https://elinux.org/Kernel_Timer_Systems).

Comment: @MurrayJensen Thanks for this hint but jiffies is too coarse. This is on a small device, I don't know the exact value right now but the jiffies rate is far below 1000. This resolution is larger than a millisecond but must be more exact. The function in my example would be great if it didn't return an error in some cases. Strange to see reading a simple ticker is such a rocket science.

Comment: You are making a simple thing complicated by calling a user process system call in your kernel code (generally speaking, things that start with `sys_` are often system calls - haven't seen `compat_sys_` before, but probably the same ... it is, see [this](https://ess.cs.tu-dortmund.de/lockdoc-elixir/linux-lockdoc/lockdebug-v4.10-0.7/source/include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h#L353)). If jiffies are too coarse for you, you will have to read a hardware time base register (which makes your code platform dependent). Maybe there is a platform independent way to do this (I would like to know).

Comment: @MurrayJensen Oh a good point, I didn't thinkk about sys_. I wrote an answer how I do this now..

Answer (score 1):

As of lately I am using `ktime_get`.

I have no idea if there is something better or if this function is so common it's a good idea to use it. But this function seems to return a small resolution and is at least not incredibly slow.
Also it has no return value which implies it shouldn't fail but reliably return a time.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer - this looks to me like the right thing to use (read [this](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/core-api/timekeeping.html))

Comment: Thanks, that helped! For those wondering how to use it: the body of [this question has a working usage example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36299528/2388257#how-to-get-high-precision-nano-second-delay-in-linux).

Comment: According to man, the call can fail with -EINVAL
 if you provide an invalid clock or -EFAULT if the value fails to copy to the tp struct . The source code seems to be this one ```long compat_sys_clock_gettime(clockid_t which_clock,
  struct compat_timespec __user *tp)
{
 long err;
 mm_segment_t oldfs;
 struct timespec ts;

 oldfs = get_fs();
 set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
 err = sys_clock_gettime(which_clock,
    (struct timespec __user *) &ts);
 set_fs(oldfs);
 if (!err && put_compat_timespec(&ts, tp))
  return -EFAULT;
 return err;
}```